# Filter Last child when Hover Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have problem When I want to create inpector plugin of jquery, If I am select child of element should be not select parent element.

[image]

That is inpect with double border actualy only home element is inspected but that is follow by parent.

this is my jsfiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Rp7hr/46/
```

and this code how my plugin called

```
$(function(){

    //generate dropdown list   
    var test = $('.summary').ksinspect();


});
```

and I don't understand why element on iframe tag is cannot be hover ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect you see is becuase of Event Bubbling.
to stop that you should use [**event.stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Here is updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rp7hr/48/)**

See updated

```
_ks.onMouseOver = function() {
    var el = ktm.query(document).find('*');
    el.on('mouseenter',function(e){
        e.stopPropagation(); // THIS is newly added line...
        var d = new Date();
        var id = d.getTime() + randomID(1);
        var parents = ktm.query(this).parents("*");
        var getParents = _get_parents(ktm.query(this));
        ktm.query(this).attr('data-key',id); //add attr data-key
        ktm.query(getParents).removeClass('glare'); //remove class
        ktm.query("[data-key=" + id + "]").addClass('glare'); //add class 
        console.log("selector = " + getParents);
        console.log("cusrrent selector = " + this);
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks that is work, did yu know why element on iframe is cannot hover ?

Comment: @viyancs which browser you are cheking iframe in? in chrome it looks good without any issues On IFRAME.. However elements within IFrame document might not work because of security issues.
If this solved your issue please accept as answer

Comment: security issue ? can you give me reference for this, I need to my riset. I am using chrome 26.

Comment: @viyancs Iframe can have contents from different domain, and allowing the javascript access to IFRames DOM elements can cause security concerns .. some idea is at http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy... consider you opened  xyz.com in iframe.. and in your javascript you attached say `keydown` event to password and userId field from xyz... then your code can actually manipulate with xyz.com or read or observe whats user is doing and then send it to your server with the help of ajax...